# How to wake Ubuntu 20.04 running on external SSD after suspension?

Tags: suspend, ssd

I'm running Ubuntu on a SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD. When I suspend it and want to wake it up, it shows a black screen with a cursor looks like this `_` blinking on the top left. I suspect that when Ubuntu goes into suspend mode, there isn't power supply to the external SSD, is there a fix?

- Acer Aspire 7
- I7-8750h
- Nvidia 1050
- Dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu

Comment: Your suspicion is correct and no, there's no "fix". Linux running from external drives is doable but has its limitations.

Comment: What happens if you type at that blinking cursor? Have you tried typing `reboot` and then enter?

Comment: Just tried, I wasn't able to type anything.

Comment: OK so your only option is to stop it going to sleep. And that does not seem like a normal feature SO you can investigate two Linux packages that I have used in the past to controll HDD so good luck. The packages are hdparm and/or tlp. You can guggle them or search here or even on https://wiki.archlinux.org

Answer (score 0):

Go into your BIOS setting, under Power setting and change the sleep mode from "Windows"(if Windows was your previous OS)